# how to delete lowercase words from a string in python

Tags: python, list

I'm new in python and I'm having some issues doing a simple thing.

I've an array (or list as it's said in python) like this:

```
 list = [ 'NICE dog' , 'blue FLOWER' , 'GOOD cat' , 'YELLOW caw']
```

As you see each element of this array contains some words. These words is both lowercase and uppercase.

How I can delete from this array each lowercase words?

For example I'd like to have as result this list:

```
list = [ 'NICE' , 'FLOWER' , 'GOOD' , 'YELLOW']
```

Comment: don't overwrite the built-in `list`!

Comment: Do you need to consider mixed case words? E.g., `'NICE Little dog'`. How should those be handled?

Comment: If the string is "NICE Little dog" I'd like to retrive only 'NICE'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
l = [ 'NICE dog' , 'blue FLOWER' , 'GOOD cat' , 'YELLOW caw']

output = [' '.join(w for w in a.split() if w.isupper())  for a in l]
# or:    
output = [' '.join(filter(str.isupper, a.split())) for a in l]
```

returns:

```
['NICE', 'FLOWER', 'GOOD', 'YELLOW']
```

(Don't use `list` as variable name.)

Answer (score 3):

The following will do it:

```
def remove_lower(s):
    return ' '.join(w for w in s.split(' ') if not w.islower())

l = [ 'NICE dog' , 'blue FLOWER' , 'GOOD cat' , 'YELLOW caw']

l = map(remove_lower, l)
```

Answer (score 2):

`string.translate()` will quickly delete specified characters:

```
>>> import string
>>> mylist=['NICE dog', 'blue FLOWER', 'GOOD cat', 'YELLOW caw']
>>> print [s.translate(None, string.ascii_lowercase) for s in mylist]
['NICE', 'FLOWER', 'GOOD', 'YELLOW']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with the `re` (regular expression) module:

```
list = map(lambda l: re.sub(r'\b\w*[a-z]+\w*\b','',l).strip(), list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [ 'NICE dog' , 'blue FLOWER' , 'GOOD cat' , 'YELLOW caw']

print [word for pair in list for word in pair.split() if not word.islower()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [ 'NICE dog' , 'blue FLOWER' , 'GOOD cat' , 'YELLOW caw']

for i in range(len(lst)):
    tmp = ""
    for j in range(len(lst[i])):
        if ord(lst[i][j]) <= ord('Z'):
            tmp = tmp + lst[i][j]
    lst[i] = tmp.strip()
print(lst) #['NICE', 'FLOWER', 'GOOD', 'YELLOW']
```